# HTTP Watchdog iOS Application

Tags: ios, applications, webserver

Is there some application for iOS that alerts me if a HTTP server is down?

I am looking for a simple app that sends an HTTP GET request to a URL of my choice several times a day. It can e.g. show a notification if no response is returned or if the HTTP status of the response is out of 2xx range.

Search for `watchdog` or `http watchdog` in App Store gave me no relevant result.

Comment: AFAIK apps aren't active in the background long enough to make this useful. Using IFTTT with a Date & Time trigger might be an option though.

Comment: Take a look at [Pingdom](https://www.pingdom.com/).  As part of their service they offer an iOS app.  The service does the actual monitoring and the app allows you to access those logs.

Comment: @fsb I took a look at Pingdom and it seems to be an overkill for such trivial requirement. If there is no appropriate app, I will probably write some simple script scheduled by cron on my notebook instead.

Comment: You didn't mention if you have any control over the server. If you do, you can put a script there as a deadman switch that periodically sends an "I'm Alive" message to your phone via IFTTT or SMS or other notification tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe nohillside and fsb are indeed correct.

Monitoring the status of a website is something that iOS was never intended to do, except manually. By actually visiting the website and seeing if it is up or not. Using a phone to do such tasks (assuming it is even possible) will likely eat up battery power and might even fail depending on how strong your local WiFi or cellular signal is. Remember you are running a background task that is *always running in the background.* A service that needs to use the WiFi/cellular radio. All of which have a cost in battery life.

So it is likely your best bet is an internet service that monitors websites. On my Wordpress blog there is a feature built in to one of the standard plugins to notify me if it goes down. There are other services like Pingdom (no doubt you can find a free one) that do exactly what you want and will notify you of downtime.

Comment: I do not expect the app to run permanently. If it sends the request just few times a day, it will be OK for me. I guess there must be some apps that download e.g. weather forecast at least once a day. (I admit that I do not use such application. I just guess it must exist.) If I want to check that a server is not down just few times a day, it seems to be exactly the same task technically.

Comment: @Cimlman Weather forecasts either refresh the moment you open the app, or use push notifications. They don't actively poll a server.

Comment: @nohillside ...and does such weather forecast app download the forecast when it shows a notification?

Comment: @cimlman Don't know whether this is possible but the key is that the notification is triggered from outside, the app is not aware of anything going on. So in your scenario you still need a daemon running on a 24/7 machine which checks host availability and notifies the app (or uses IFTTT to notify you).